# Ajax call to controller is sending data, but i cannot use it if an if statement

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

> Here is my controller. I am trying to pass the value through an if statement but it's not equalling (==) the string of "2019".

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Extract(string[] response)
    {
        string statementQuery = "";
        if (response!=null)
        {

            for (var i = 0; i < response.Length; i++)
            {
                if (response[i] == "2019")
                {
                    statementQuery = "select statementPath from ClientStatements_Inventory where statementYear = '" + response[i] + "';";
                }


            }



        }
```

> Here is my ajax call. Is it something to do with the way it is sending to my controller? or my if statement?

```
$('#main-content-submit').click(function () {

    var labelArray = [];
    labelArray = $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
        return $(this).closest('label').text();
    }).get();
    console.log(labelArray);
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/Extract',
        data: JSON.stringify({ response:labelArray }),

        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (result) {
            alert("Month and ear passed to controller");
        },
        error: function (err, result) {
            alert("Error in Extract" + err.responseText);
        },

    });
return false;
});
```

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(labelArray);`?

Comment: its an array of the years and month that was checked (ie. [2012, 2014, 2020, September, August, January]

Comment: `2019` if not exist in `labelArray`, so any member of array is equal to 2019?what is exactly the issue?